# Java Abstract Class and types

Tags: java, abstract-class, bytebuffer

I read this line of code in [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html) :
`ByteBuffer out = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);`
How can object `out` be declared if `ByteBuffer` is an abstract class and abstract classes can't be istantiated ?

`ByteBuffer.wrap()` return a `ByteBuffer`, but being `ByteBuffer` an abstract class, what is the implementation class of `ByteBuffer` the method wrap does return?

Comment: Because you didn't instantiate ByteBuffer.  You called a static method that returned an instance of some subclass of ByteBuffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `wrap()` method returns a specific `ByteBuffer` implementation, in this case `HeapByteBuffer`.

See `wrap` implementation from `jdk1.6.0_43_src.zip`

```
public static ByteBuffer wrap(byte[] array, int offset, int length)
{
    try {
        return new HeapByteBuffer(array, offset, length);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException x) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not a consructor call, it is a call of a static method.
Abstract classes can have non-abstract methods.

A constructor call would look like this:

```
ByteBuffer out = new ByteBuffer(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but their subclasses (if not abstract as well) can.

In this particular example, according to ByteBuffer source, calling ByteBuffer.wrap() (note that a static method is called, not a constructor) gets you an instance of HeapByteBuffer, a subclass of ByteBuffer.

I'm assuming that you are trying to grasp the concept of **[subtype polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping)**: **You want a ByteBuffer, you get one.** You really don't need to care about the particular implementation. **It is a given that any implementation you get will provide the functionality declared in ByteBuffer's contract.**